# How Do I Get the userId From the Login Manager User Loader?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

So I've got a flask web app and everything runs fine except for the login portion. I'm using flask's login manager and I'm having a problem loading the userid from the user loader.

```
@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
    u = User.query.get(userid)
    return User(u.password, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.datecreated)
```

This is how my user model is defined:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100),)
    firstname = db.Column(db.String(100),)
    lastname = db.Column(db.String(100),)
    email = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True)
    datecreated = db.Column(db.Date,)

    def __init__(self,password, firstname, lastname, email, datecreated):
        self.password = password
        self.firstname = firstname
        self.lastname = lastname
        self.email = email
        if datecreated == None:
            self.datecreated = datetime.date.today()
        else:
            self.datecreated = datecreated

    def get_id(self):
        return chr(self.id)

    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    def is_active(self):
        return True

    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.id)
```

I'm getting a 500 server error when I try and log in, but when I hard code a user id for the query everything works fine, you're just always logged in as that user. I've tried converting it to an int but I get an `invalid literal for int()` error.

Here's the traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1701, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1689, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 756, in decorated_view
elif not current_user.is_authenticated():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 338, in __getattr__
return getattr(self._get_current_object(), name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 297, in _get_current_object
return self.__local()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 46, in <lambda>
current_user = LocalProxy(lambda: _get_user())
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 794, in _get_user
current_app.login_manager._load_user()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 363, in _load_user
return self.reload_user()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask_login.py", line 325, in reload_user
user = self.user_callback(user_id)
line 19, in load_user
return User(u.password, u.firstname, u.lastname, u.email, u.datecreated)
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated since I'm really new to this. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a traceback? Which line is that error on? If it's `u = User.query.get(userid)`, what's the value of `userid`?

Comment: do you have app.debug = True ? Need to see the traceback.

Comment: I added the traceback and the changed the code to what I'm actually running. It looks like the the query isn't returning anything when I know that it should be. I don't know how to tell what the value of `userid` actually is though

Comment: did you update your load_user code ? The error traceback shows something different than what you have now posted in the question

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry! I'll update it, but the problem is still the same. I can't tell what `userid` is and the query is returning `None` which I know isn't the case

Comment: How is your User Model defined ? Also, I think you are overcomplicating the load_user. Just return User.query.get(userid). No need to create a User instance again.

Comment: I agree. I came to that realization a little while ago. But I'm still not getting anything from the query. When you hard code a value (say, 7) in place of `userid` everything works just fine, you are just always logged in under whoever has and id of 7 in the user table. I'll also upload my User model